# Lock thead to top of page Twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I noticed that when you scroll a page with twitter bootstrap it locks the navbar to the top of the screen.  I was wondering if this is possible to lock a `<thead>` up there when it is scrolled into it.  Not sure if this is related or not, but when I print it puts the navbar at the top of every page and I am looking to do the same with the `<thead>` again.

I have no idea where to start and would appreciate any suggestions or points in the right direction.

Comment: There are [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11193207/1478467) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11483378/1478467) but Twitter Bootstrap won't suffice. If making a duplicate of the `<thead>` in `<ul>` and showing it as the fixed-top-submenu (as in the docs) is ok, then it may be the easier solution.